# Splunk Dashboard. Multiselect depends on another multiselect

Tags: splunk-dashboard

I'm trying to get one **multiselect** depend to another multiselect. I have come to a point where I show the another multiselect when I select `Opt1`. That's how I want it. But I also want `multiselect2` to appear when I select `Opt1` and `Opt2`.

If I first select `Opt1` and then `Opt2`, the second multiselect is displayed. But not when I select `Opt2` and then `Opt1`. How do I make the second `multiselect` appear then as well?

```html
<form theme="dark">
    <label>concept</label>
    <fieldset submitButton="true" autoRun="false">
        <input type="multiselect" token="index">
            <label>Index</label>

            <choice value="opt1">Opt1</choice>
            <choice value="opt2">Opt2</choice>

            <change>
                <condition value="opt2">
                    <unset token="opt1_selected"></unset>
                </condition>

                <condition value="opt1">
                    <set token="opt1_selected"></set>
                </condition>
            </change>

            <delimiter> OR </delimiter>
            <default>Opt1</default>
        </input>

        <input type="multiselect" token="Menu2" depends="$opt1_selected$">
            <label>Multi2</label>
        </input>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per experience, I have found that working with tokens is not that straightforward when `submitButton` attribute is set to `true`.

Unless the submit button is important to your use case, please see below Simple XML code where I turned that attribute to `false`.

```
<form theme="dark">
  <label>Sample</label>
  <init>
    <set token="show">true</set>
  </init>
  <fieldset submitButton="false" autoRun="false">
    <input type="multiselect" token="index">
      <label>Index</label>
      <choice value="opt1">Opt1</choice>
      <choice value="opt2">Opt2</choice>
      <change>
        <condition match="match($index$,&quot;opt1&quot;) OR match($index$,&quot;opt2&quot;)">
          <set token="show">true</set>
        </condition>
        <condition match="NOT match($index$,&quot;opt1&quot;) OR match($index$,&quot;opt2&quot;)">
          <unset token="show">true</unset>
        </condition>
      </change>
      <delimiter> OR </delimiter>
      <default>opt1</default>
    </input>
    <input type="multiselect" token="Menu2" depends="$show$">
      <label>Multi2</label>
    </input>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

This solution should work with the following value combinations:
`opt1`,
`opt1 OR opt2`,
`opt2`, and
`opt2 OR opt1`.

*Explanation:*

The trick is in evaluating the `index` token which holds the *final* selection value(s). You can use the `match` attribute inside the `<condition>` tag which allows you to validate the token with an eval-like expression.

```
...
<condition match="match($index$,&quot;opt1&quot;) OR match($index$,&quot;opt2&quot;)">
   <set token="show">true</set>
</condition>
...
```

The logic of this expression is to "match", or compare, the input string (value of token `index`) against a regex (`opt1` OR `opt2`). Note that for this expression to work, you have to escape some characters (e.g. quotation marks into `&quot;`) using [HTML entities](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.3/Viz/OverviewofSimplifiedXML).

If a match is found, the condition is satisfied and will proceed to perform the setting of the token `show`.

```
...
   <set token="show">true</set>
...
```

Otherwise, it will continue to the evaluate the next condition (which is basically the same expression but negated with the NOT operator), and then proceed to unset token `show`.

```
...
<condition match="NOT match($index$,&quot;opt1&quot;) OR match($index$,&quot;opt2&quot;)">
   <unset token="show">true</unset>
</condition>
...
```